# custom file names for PubSubToText dataflow template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using PubsubToText google-provided streaming template to ingests incoming data from a Cloud Pub/Sub topic and output data into windowed files at the specified output directory.

Its creating files in the below format:
**prefix2021-07-26T15:30:00.000Z-2021-07-26T15:35:00.000Z-pane-0-last-00-of-01suffix**

but I want to have in below format:
**prefix.MMDDYYYYHHMISS.suffix**

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if you can do this directly in dataflow template. But one solution is to create a cloud function triggered by [Google Cloud Storage `google.storage.object.finalize` event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize), that will rename your file as you like and push it back to another cloud storage bucket.